# Extracting EMF from EMF Spool?

Tags: windows, metafile

Windows EMF Spool files format are well-known and documented, but i cannot seem to understand how I can extract information from the spool file. Right now, what I'm trying to achieve is to extract the EMF from the SPL file (as a general rule, it should be present).
I already know the spool file is defined by structures, like this:

```
Private Enum SpoolerRecordTypes
SRT_EOF = &H0 ' // int32 zero
SRT_RESERVED_1 = &H1 '* 1 */
SRT_FONTDATA = &H2 ' 2 Font Data */
SRT_DEVMODE = &H3 ' 3 DevMode */
SRT_FONT2 = &H4 '4 Font Data */
SRT_RESERVED_5 = &H5 ' 5 */
SRT_FONT_MM = &H6 ' 6 Font Data (Multiple Master) */
SRT_FONT_SUB1 = &H7 ' 7 Font Data (SubsetFont 1) */
SRT_FONT_SUB2 = &H8 ' 8 Font Data (SubsetFont 2)
SRT_RESERVED_9 = &H9
SRT_UNKNOWN = &H10 ' // int unknown...
SRT_RESERVED_A = &HA
SRT_RESERVED_B = &HB
SRT_PAGE = &HC ' 12 Enhanced Meta File (EMF) */
SRT_EOPAGE1 = &HD ' 13 EndOfPage */
SRT_EOPAGE2 = &HE ' 14 EndOfPage */
SRT_EXT_FONT = &HF ' 15 Ext Font Data */
SRT_EXT_FONT2 = &H10 ' 16 Ext Font Data */
SRT_EXT_FONT_MM = &H11 ' 17 Ext Font Data (Multiple Master)
SRT_EXT_FONT_SUB1 = &H12 ' 18 Ext Font Data (SubsetFont 1) */
SRT_EXT_FONT_SUB2 = &H13 '* 19 Ext Font Data (SubsetFont 2) */
SRT_EXT_PAGE = &H14 ' 20 Enhanced Meta File?
SRT_JOB_INFO = &H10000 ' // int length, wchar jobDescription
End Enum
```

Also, after each structure, there is an unsigned 32 bit number that defined the size of the structure.
Does anyone know how can I extract information from the spool file using these structures?

PS: I know there are some programs out there that show a live preview of an EMF, so I know this is possible. I must be able to do this programmatically, though.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: For those of you wondering where it is documented, look at [MS-EMFSPOOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231034.aspx).

Comment: Yes, thanks, forgot to include it.